# Trying to read var before jsonp request is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm trying to create a variable from the result of a jsonp request, and the use this variable later in the script. But it seems like the part where the variable is used is triggered before the jsonp request is done.

```
  function onSuccess(data) {
    var result = data['result'];
    console.log(result);
}

function onError(data) {
    alert(data);
}

$.ajax({
    url:"http://suneeriksen.unboxer.org/",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});


var gallery,
    el,
    i,
    page,
    dots = document.querySelectorAll('#nav li'),
    slides = result //this is where I try to fetch the variable

    ];
```

I've tried to figure out how this could be done. I've tried to put the jsonp request in a function and done like this:
    var slides = jsonpResult();

Any clue what to do?

EDIT:
I also have functions using the gallery variable

```
gallery.onFlip(function () {
//Doing stuff
}
```

And I can't put all of these in the onSuccess function.

Comment: Well, what you *can't* do is access result where you are trying to access it. Instead any code that depends on the `result` variable needs to be placed inside of the `success` callback.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have functions that will be called later on that depends on the gallery var. I added some more info to my question.

Comment: The only other way to do it (without using `async:false` which is bad) is to store the `jqXHR` object and later on bind an event to the done when you need to run code that needs the data that it returned.

Comment: Do you mean store like in local storage? I don't thing I really understood you.

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TkuQB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

Make the AJAX call not A(synchronous) by setting `async: true` at the ajax call options (please note that this approach is now deprecated).

or:

do call whatever code that uses the `slides` variable from inside the success callback (*and do the assigning there as well, if you need it for future use*).

Answer (score 3):

Bind it for onSuccess - don't call the function that uses it until onSuccess occurs.
You could also force your request to be synchronous (no code will execute until your ajax has run) but I highly recommend you don't.

Comment: I've tried that, but it seems like since the success triggers a function it doesn't bother for that to finish.